# Two tk windows instead of one

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am new to tkinter and I would like to create a tkinter interface with "entries" , a canvas with a picture , and a button. I expected only one tk window but there is a second small empty tk window when I run my code. I guess it is because of the class I use but I'm not sure.. 
Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
import time

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self,transfo,nb_itération):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.transfo = transfo
        self.nb_itération = nb_itération



    def affichage_graphique(self):

        self.matrix_hex = extraction_rgb(tk.PhotoImage(file='obama_128.gif'))
        self.width , self.height = len(self.matrix_hex[0]) , len(self.matrix_hex)
        self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = 8*self.width+6, 8*self.height+6
        self.cnv = Canvas(self, width=self.WIDTH, height=self.HEIGHT, bg='white',highlightthickness=0)
        self.cnv.grid(row = 2 , columnspan = 3)
        self.txt1 = Label(self, text = 'Transformation :').grid(row = 0 , sticky = E)
        self.txt2 = Label(self, text = 'Nombre d\'itérations : ').grid(row = 1 , sticky = E)
        self.entr1 = Entry(self)
        self.entr2 = Entry(self)

        self.entr1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.entr2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.destroy).grid(row = 0 , column = 2)

        if self.transfo == photomaton or self.transfo == boulanger:

            print("valeur par défaut mauvaise")
            self.cnv.delete(ALL)
            self.img01 = self.PhotoImage(width=self.width*4, height=self.height*4)
            self.img = self.PhotoImage(width=self.width*4, height=self.height*4)

            self.matrix_hex4 = [[x for x in range(self.width*4)] for y in range(self.height*4)]
            self.matrix_4 = [[x for x in range(self.width*4)] for y in range(self.height*4)]


            self.img.put(data=self.matrix_4 , to=(0,0))   
            self.cnv.create_image(0, 0, image=self.img, anchor=tk.NW)

            self.img01.put(data=self.matrix_hex4, to=(0,0))
            self.cnv.create_image(self.WIDTH, 0, image=self.img01, anchor=tk.NE)
            self.cnv.bind('<Button-1>',self.click_handler)

        else:

            self.img = tk.PhotoImage(width=self.width*4, height=self.height*4)
            self.img.put(data=self.matrix_4 , to=(0,0))   
            self.cnv.create_image(0, 0, image=self.img, anchor=tk.NW)
            self.entr1.insert(0,"photomaton")
            self.entr2.insert(0,"1")
            self.entr2.bind("<Return>",Programme().Enter)



class Programme(Application):
    def __init__(self,transfo = 0, nb_itération = 0 ,orbites  =[],période = []):
        self.choice = 0
        self.orbites = orbites
        self.période = période
        self.transfo = transfo
        self.nb_itération = nb_itération
        Application.__init__(self, self.transfo , self.nb_itération)


    def Enter(self,event):
        self.choix_transfo = self.entr1.get()
        self.nb_itération = self.entr2.get()
        return self.choix_transfo , self.nb_itération

    def start(self):
        self.affichage_graphique()



prog = Programme()
prog.start()
prog.mainloop()
```

Comment: There are a couple of errors in your code that prevent me from running it, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, `Program.__init__` is missing a colon after the argument list. Also, there is an infinite recursion in `Program.__init__`.

Comment: My guess would be that (a) you have several classes that all extend `Tk`, or (b) you have one class that extends `Tk` and also manually create a "root" `Tk` instance. Can't check, though, because your code has errors (syntax and runtime). I suggest not extending `Tk` at all, but `Frame`.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that will create two windows. However, I see your use of `Programme()` but there is no class or function by that name. You have a class named `Program` -- is one of those a typo?

Comment: @FamousJameous: why do you say `Program.__init__` has infinite recursion? There's no recursion there.

Comment: @BryanOakley I get infinite recursion on the attribute lookup when accessing `self.trf` and `self.nbi` in `Program.__init__`. The recursion appears to be on `Tk.__getattr__`. Probably beacuse Program tries to use attributes that would be initialized in Application but `Application.__init__` hasn't run yet.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code that prevents it from even running for anyone copy pasting into their IDE. `Programme` does not exist as a function/method. `def Enter(self):` has nothing in it so the program will expect indention of your next line. Put `pass` here at least if u need filler. `extraction_rgb` is non existent. I am assuming you are in python 3 because you imported tkinter in lower case. In any case please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @tobias_k: yes, that absolutely will create a second window if it's a typo. That is why I asked for clarification on that point. My guess is that the code in this question isn't the real code, because _this_ code won't create two windows.

Comment: I edited my question and added the complete code !

Comment: We don't need complete code, we need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Please try to reduce the code down to something that is as small as possible but still runs, and still exhibits the error that you say it does. Also, we don't need to see two versions of the program. Edit your answer, delete both examples, and then add a new example that is similar to the first example but without the syntax errors and typos.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be on this line:

```
    self.entr2.bind("<Return>",Programme().Enter)
```

This line has multiple problems:

1. it will create a *second* `Program()` instance (assuming that this is a typo), thus creating a second `Tk` window (because `Program` extends `Tk`)
2. it will do so *immediately*, not only when the button is clicked, and bind the method of that new instance to the button

Instead, you probably want to use

```
    self.entr2.bind("<Return>", self.Enter)
```

to call the `Enter` method of the current `Program` instance, or

```
    self.entr2.bind("<Return>", lambda: Program().Enter)
```

if you actually *want* to create a second `Program` window when the button is clicked; however, in this case you will also have to call the `gui` method in order to initialize the widgets.

---

Note that there are a few other problems in your code, as discussed in comments, but I assume that those don't exist in your actual code, otherwise you would not get that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new window in two places. First, with this:

```
prog = Programme()
```

The second is here:

```
self.entr2.bind("<Return>",Programme().Enter)
```

Why? The above code is functionally identical to this:

```
p = Programme()
self.entr2.bind("<Return>", p.Enter)
```

The normal way to call functions defined in your program class is to use the existing reference. Since your code is being run in a method belonging to the `Programme` class, you can do this:

```
self.entr2.bind("<Return>", self.Enter)
```

Comment: The "entry.bind" method creates a window ? What can i do to avoid that ? Put "Enter" in the Application class ?

Comment: Thx for your help !

Comment: @NathanDubois: no, `entry.bind` doesn't create a window, `Program().Enter` makes a window because `Program()` makes a window.

Comment: @NathanDubois: I've updated my answer to reflect the edits made in your question.

Comment: "The above code is functionally identical to this" Is it? Maybe I'm missing something here, but using `some_func` as a callback will _not_ create a `Program()` instance immediately when `bind` is called.

Comment: @tobias_k: thanks. You are correct. I based that last section on some earlier code. I'm trying to answer a moving target! I'll update the answer.