# Why are two tkinter windows being created when one Tk window is defined?

Tags: python, tkinter

Two tkinter windows are getting created when I define one Tk window. I have three files, main, app_class, style_class.

```
import App_class as a
import style_class as s

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = a.App()
   root.mainloop()
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(2)
```

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

style = ttk.Style()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("style")
```

Is there a reason why?

When you delete the `import style_class as s`  line in the main.py file, the second tkinter doesn't get called. But I havent defined anything that creates a TK window.

There is a similar post: [Two tk windows instead of one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310641/two-tk-windows-instead-of-one), but the answers all state that the problem was due to TK window being called twice in the code.

Answer (score 2):

`ttk.Style` requires that a root window exists before it can work. When you import that file no root window exists, so it creates one. Then, you create an instance of `App` that is also a root window.

You can easily visualize this by calling `ttk.Style()` in an interactive session without having created any windows.